# Better way to make node not exit?

Tags: node.js

In a node program I'm reading from a file stream with `fs.createReadStream`. But when I pause the stream the program exits. I thought the program would keep running since the file is still opened, just not being read.

Currently to get it to not exit I'm setting an interval that does nothing.

```
setInterval(function() {}, 10000000);
```

When I'm ready to let the program exit, I clear it. But is there a better way?

#### Example Code where node will exit:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var rs = fs.createReadStream('file.js');
rs.pause();
```

Comment: Can we see some example code, with event handlers, etc?

Comment: An example script that recreates the problems seems essential here.

Comment: @mike jinx! you owe me a soda

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Node will exit when there is no more queued work. Calling `pause` on a `ReadableStream` simply pauses the `data` event. At that point, there are no more events being emitted and no outstanding work requests, so Node will exit. The `setInterval` works since it counts as queued work.

Generally this is not a problem since you will probably be doing *something* after you pause that stream. Once you `resume` the stream, there will be a bunch of queued I/O and your code will execute before Node exits.

Let me give you an example. Here is a script that exits without printing anything:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var rs = fs.createReadStream('file.js');
rs.pause();

rs.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data); // never gets executed
});
```

The stream is paused, there is no outstanding work, and my callback never runs.

However, this script does actually print output:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var rs = fs.createReadStream('file.js');
rs.pause();

rs.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log(data); // prints stuff
});

rs.resume(); // queues I/O
```

In conclusion, as long as you are eventually calling `resume` later, you should be fine.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ) is good for gaining a better understanding of the JavaScript event loop and how work is queued.

Answer (score 1):

Short way based on answers below

`require('fs').createReadStream('file.js').pause();`