# Stop node.js process exiting when using process.on to listen for messages

Tags: node.js, messaging

The following trivial script exits immediately:

```
process.on('message', function () { });
```

What is the correct way to keep a node.js process running while listening for messages?

Comment: Could this be related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8989780/better-way-to-make-node-not-exit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always do `process.stdin.resume();` which will hold your process open until EOF is received on stdin or you explicitly exit (the stdin stream is initially paused to prevent this from happening unless you really want it to).